# How to unsplit packages / merge modules

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javafx, java-module

I am currently trying to build a project in java 11, using maven, and also javafx.

Using javafx seems to kind of require defining module for your own project. Since I am managing my dependencies with maven, adding it with `--module-path /path/to/javafx-sdk-13/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml` and thus avoiding the own module-info file isn't really an option.

However, defining the module and running with it causes an issue with a split package in one of my other dependencies, in particular, `module reads package org.apache.http.impl.client.cache from both org.apache.httpcomponents.httpasyncclient.cache and httpclient.cache` caused by group `org.apache.httpcomponents` and artifact `httpclient-cache` and `httpasyncclient-cache`.

Both of these are required by the dependency `com.atlassian.jira:jira-rest-java-client-core` my project is using.

The most promising "fix" for this I have seen so far is using the --patch-module option, however defining that seemed to do nothing for me, maybe I put it in the wrong place or used it wrongly? I'm not sure if there might be a way to define it in the pom as well, but I tried the following in intellij's run configuration in `VM options`: `--patch-module httpclient.cache=C:\Users\Daniel\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpasyncclient-cache\4.1.4\httpasyncclient-cache-4.1.4.jar`.
The only other option I currently see would be to just migrate to java 1.8 again to just avoid all of this module nonsense completely. I would kinda hate that since I feel like I'm super close to a working thing, but I'm also kinda frustrated by getting weird errors I'm not even responsible for.

In case that helps, here is my current pom file:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>neuneinser</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>atlassian-public</id>
            <url>https://packages.atlassian.com/content/repositories/atlassian-public</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>13.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Has a broken module name, included version 4.4.11 manually which fixes this -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                    <artifactId>httpcore-nio</artifactId>
                </exclusion>

                <!-- included in jdk 11 -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.xml.stream</groupId>
                    <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore-nio</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.atlassian.fugue</groupId>
            <artifactId>fugue</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>neuneinser.testproject.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Note you can still place your code and all its dependencies, including JavaFX, on the classpath. With everything on the classpath the split packages should not be a problem. This will require that your main-class _is not_ the `Application` implementation. Also, using `jlink` may become difficult, if not impossible, but if you aren't already creating a custom image then that shouldn't matter. You also have the option to put compatible libraries on the modulepath while keeping the non-compatible libraries on the classpath. [cont.]

Comment: Keep in mind that explicit (i.e. named & non-automatic) modules, when used on the modulepath, cannot depend on classes on the classpath. You may also wish to submit a bug report to the maintainers of the problematic libraries, assuming one doesn't already exist. If the library is ever to be used in modular applications then the maintainers need to fix the split package problem.

Comment: Using the classpath and a different Main class from the one that extends Application seems to fix this indeed.
Feels very hacky, but it's fine by me^^ Thank you!

Comment: Also submitted it to their issue tracker, as I couldn't find it being mentioned somewhere else, so hopefully this won't be a problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

As Slaw suggested, I am now using the classpath only, with a main class that does not extend Application. Problem solved.

Comment: In contrast to what was said before you can also make use of jlink and jpackage without problem if you follow this route. Just have a look here: https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX